# Got Error: Field `message_follower_ids` does not exist when trying inherit employee form

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I'm facing this issue for 2 days and no luck to find the way how to resolve it without reading any links regarding the same error

I'm just create a simple module call insurance and add it as a new tab in employee view form

here is my view file

```
    <record id='social_insurance_tab' model='ir.ui.view'>
        <field name='social.insurance.tab'></field>
        <field name='model'>hr.insurance</field>
        <field name='inherit_id' ref='hr.view_employee_form'></field>
        <field name='arch' type='xml'>
            <notebook position="inside">
                <page name='insurance' string='Social Insurance'>
                    <group string="Informations">
                        <group>
                            <field name='name'></field>
                            <field name='employee_id'></field>
                            <field name='date_join'></field>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name='amount'></field>
                            <field name='salary'></field>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <label for='notes' string="Notes"/>
                    <field name="notes"/>
                </page>
            </notebook>     
        </field>
    </record>
```

and model file

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class hr_insurance(models.Model):
    _name = 'hr.insurance'

    _description = 'Insurance'

    _order = 'id desc'

    name = fields.Many2one('hr.contract', string='Insurance', required=True)

    employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Employee', required=True)

    date_join = fields.Date('Date join Insurance', required=True)

    amount = fields.Float('Amount of social insurance')

    salary = fields.Float('Salary Social insurance')

    notes = fields.Text('Notes')
```

I also add hr into depends in **openerp**.py

```
'depends': ['base_action_rule','hr'],
```

And it always return this error

```
ParseError: "Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `message_follower_ids` does not exist

Error context:
View `insurance.tab`
[view_id: 1462, xml_id: n/a, model: hr.insurance, parent_id: 905]
None" while parsing      /opt/odoo/odoo/addons/hr_insurance/hr_insurance_view.xml:66, near
<record id="insurance_tab" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">insurance.tab</field>
        <field name="model">hr.insurance</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <xpath expr="//notebook" position="inside">
                    <page string="Insurance">
                        <field name="name"/>
                    </page>  
                </xpath>                    
            </data>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: I see what you did there. It is hard to explain. In your view you inherit an already existing view `hr.view_employee_form`. That view still has the field declaration `message_follower_ids`. But you changed the model declaration to your custom model `hr.insurance`. If I understand your problem right you just want to add some fields in a tab to the  `hr.employee`-view right?

Comment: yes, exactly, I create a new module with some fields and add it to employee view

Comment: I fixed it by change model in view to `hr.employee` and inherit model `hr.employee` instead of create `hr.insurance` in model file

Comment: Nice. That is what I mean. Pay attention to your `name` field. You probably overwrite this field. Not sure, but you should prove that. The type of `name` field in `hr.employee` is `char` by default. If you inherit that model the way you do it in model. You will overwrite it to a `many2one` field.

Comment: I change field name to insurance and it 's ok now, tks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem is on the line specified bellow

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To inherit `Employee form` you will need to make some changes to your view and model.

The view name should be as following:

```
<field name='name'>social.insurance.tab</field>
```

The view model should be `hr.employee`:

```
<field name='model'>hr.employee</field>
```

To add new fields you should inherit `hr.employee` and keep the names of the original fields (unless you need to change their attributes), like `name` field which is supposed to be an employee name.
You can prefix your field names to avoid overwriting any field accidentally.

```
class HrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'

    _order = 'id desc'

    insurance_id= fields.Many2one('hr.insurance', string='Insurance', required=True)

    insurance_date_join = fields.Date('Date join Insurance', required=True)

    insurance_amount = fields.Float('Amount of social insurance')

    insurance_salary = fields.Float('Salary Social insurance')

    insurance_notes = fields.Text('Notes')
```